# Is carob bean cooked when used as a thickener?

Tags: food-science, yogurt, allergy, carob

Many yoghurts contain carob bean gum as a thickener. Does anyone know if this is raw or cooked carob bean  ?

Comment: Are you not thinking of carageenan?

Comment: The full ingredients are .. Fromage Frais (from milk), Sugar, Cream, Strawberry Puree 2.5%, Chocolate 1.8% (Sugar, Cocoa Powder, Cocoa Mass, Cocoa Butter), Modified Maize Starch, Milk Mineral Concentrate, Thickener: Guar Gum, Carob Bean Gum, Xanthan Gum, Acidity Regulator: Citric Acid, Sodium Citrate, Flavourings, Colour: Carmine, Vitamin D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Carob bean gum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locust_bean_gum) is extracted through industrial processes, not generally reproducible at home.

Per [CAROB BEAN GUM 
Chemical and Technical Assessment (CTA)](http://www.fao.org/fileadmin/templates/agns/pdf/jecfa/cta/69/Carob_bean_gum.pdf)

> The seeds are  dehusked by treating the kernels with dilute sulfuric
>   acid or with thermal mechanical treatment, elimination  of the germ
>   followed by milling and screening of the endosperm (native carob bean
>   gum). The gum may be  washed with ethanol or isopropanol to control
>   the microbiological load (washed carob bean gum). It may  also be
>   further clarified (purified, extracted) by dispersing in hot water,
>   recovery with isopropanol or  ethanol, filtering, drying and milling,
>   which is called as clarified (purified, extracted) carob bean gum. 
>   Clarified carob bean gum in the market is normally standardized with
>   sugars for viscosity and /or reactivity.